# Can bad students be good scientists?

Tags: phd, career-path

I recently moved from an undeveloped country to Europe, and I am currently a PhD student.

In my hometown, the education system is very bad, and almost everyone with some patience can get any degree. However, things do not work like this in Europe.

I have always been a bad student, and I suck at exams (both written and oral). Although I am capable of presenting my own work in an understandable fashion, when it comes to study on some topic -- that is not very related to my field of study, and learn that topic thoroughly, I fail.

Unlike the education system in my country, here, the tolerance for mediocre mistakes is close to zero. And I do make mistakes very often given limited time to evaluate my own statements/claims/proofs. My exam paper is always a mess compared to my technical reports. Because I get to write the report over on over again with an access to every term, definition, and counterexample.

Back in my country, I was the one-eyed king in the land of blind. Extraordinary researcher, and very good student. Here, everyone has both eyes with eagle vision. My research skills obviously do not shine, and if you consider my studentship, I am just a dead duck.

I do love to conduct research, and not only [looking at its butt when it walks by](http://explosm.net/comics/3557/). However, I am pretty doubtful if I can be a *good* scientist given my current achievements in the courses I take.

Should I go with the philosophy

> a fault confessed is half

or should I go with

> finish what you have started

based on your experiences?

Comment: I don't have time for a proper response and I'm not sure whether this question is really suited for this site, but, in my experience, _yes_, they can. Grades are frequently poor predictors of future academic performances because these are affected by many different factors. However, many students who have a weak background fail to become good scientists because they are not able to change their approach to learning, and instead of filling the gaps, these continue to increase.

Comment: _Can bad students be good scientists?_ — I'd like to think so, yes.

Comment: If "bad student" means "bad at school," independent of intelligence, creativity, talent, or ability to learn on your own, then yes. Doing well at "school" is a very different set of skills than doing research.

Comment: @JeffE But you're an exceptional human being. An answer or comment based on your own experiences, which are totally different than mine, would not be objective.

Comment: Close voters, I do understand where you're coming from, but please keep in mind that this question is not "what should I do" but rather "should one who is bad at exams quit PhD while it's not too late?"

Comment: If bad student is defined as a student who obtains below-average grade in all the courses, then yes (s)he is creative and can be a good scientist.

Comment: Just a comment... since you are asking this question you care about your performance and future aspirations. Many European universities have student help/skills centres that might be able to help you with some of your study issues. If you haven't tried them, give it a shot. They won't solve everything, but they could help out.

Comment: Yes and no. The group of "bad" students is pretty heterogeneous. We need to know whether your are talking about abilities or performance measures, and which ability or measure in particular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think most would probably agree that there are cases where someone is a poor student but has the potential to be a good scientists -- because what defines a good/poor student is mostly the ability to be effective in exams (i.e., most importantly to be able to learn and reproduce known material) whereas the skills necessary to be a good scientist are different.

That said, it is clearly the case that the two skill sets are highly correlated. There is a perception in the public eye that the best scientists are mavericks who are able to think outside the box and swim against the scientific consensus to find the things that nobody else sees. But in reality, that is probably a glorification and even those rare insights like quantum theory or the theory of relativity can only be found by those with profound and deep understanding of the existing knowledge, and the ability to synthesize knowledge into something new that those who have not paid the same level of attention to the details of the field can not.

As a consequence, what I read from your description in the question is that you may have the *skills* to be a good scientist, but that you lack the *knowledge* and maybe diligence to compete with your peers. That's not your fault, of course, but it's an insight that you may want to keep in mind when thinking about your future. Knowledge is, after all, something that you can catch up with if, for example,you are willing to take some time off from other responsibilities and focus on learning the basics at a more profound level than you had the opportunity to do in the past.

Comment: I'd be stunned if exam performance is well-correlated with the ability to acquire or apply knowledge effectively after controlling for intelligence and motivation.

Comment: Empirically, the professors I know almost all were pretty good students. So are many of the successful research scientists I know. There is at least a correlation. Whether you can explain it by other factors may be a different matter ("causation") but the correlation is there.